# Fancy thumbnail hover effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using a script - for a pretty small image gallery within a tabbed content area.

I'm using; http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/fancy-thumbnail-hover-effect-w-jquery/ But customized to almost a fourth the size, only 3 images, and realigned to have the thumbs sit directly below the 'main view' image area. I've done it successfully, and visually it's great.

The thumbs are about 50px, that expand to about 60px on hover and when clicked - it takes the main view area with the correct image as it's supposed too.

Problem is, and is really weird as I've used this script over and over again - for some reason the parameters of the 3 thumbs are duplicated above the main view as well - but the actual images are not visible. When a user put their mouse above the main view - anywhere between the 50px 60px square/rectangle parameter - the hover of the below images appear.

I've been going through the code over and over again - I know it's something stupid - if anyone could throw me a suggestion that'd be great.

**Here's a screenshot visual of the situation - check it out;** http://tinypic.com/r/2nt8o7t/7

**The mark-up:**

```
<!-- Thumb Gall Mark-Up -->

<div class="containerslide">

<ul class="thumb">

    <li><a href="img/appimg_1.jpg"><img src="img/appimg_1.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="img/appimg_2.jpg"><img src="img/appimg_2.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="img/appimg_3.jpg"><img src="img/appimg_3.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>


</ul>

<div id="main_view">

    <img src="img/appimg_1.jpg" alt="" /></a><br />

</div>
</div>

<!--End Thumb Gall Mark-Up-->
```

**The query:**

```
        <script src="js/modernizr.custom.37797.js"></script> 

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){

//Larger thumbnail preview 

$("ul.thumb li").hover(function() {
    $(this).css({'z-index' : '10'});
    $(this).find('img').addClass("hover").stop()
        .animate({
            marginTop: '0px', 
            marginLeft: '0',
            top: '360px', 
            left: '0',  
            width: '65px', 
            overflow: 'hidden',
            height: '80px',
            padding: '3px' 
        }, 200);

    } , function() {
    $(this).css({'z-index' : '0'});
    $(this).find('img').removeClass("hover").stop()
        .animate({
            marginTop: '0', 
            marginLeft: '0',
            top: '360px', 
            left: '0', 
            width: '60px', 
            overflow: 'hidden',
            height: '60px', 
            padding: '3px'
        }, 200);
});

//Swap Image on Click
    $("ul.thumb li a").click(function() {

        var mainImage = $(this).attr("href"); //Find Image Name
        $("#main_view img").attr({ src: mainImage });
        return false;       
    });

});
</script>
```

**The CSS;**

```
<!--minSlide Show Styles -->

* { padding: 0;}
img {border: none;}
.containerslide {
    margin-top: -71px;
}

ul.thumb {
    float: left;
    list-style: none outside none;
    padding: 12px;
    width: 360px;
}

ul.thumb {
    width: 360px;

}


ul.thumb li {
    padding: 3px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;

}
ul.thumb li img {
    width: 60px; height: 60px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 3px;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; 
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; 
    margin-top: 365px;

}
ul.thumb li img.hover {
    background:url(thumb_bg.png) no-repeat center center;
    border: none;


}
#main_view {
    float: left;
    margin-left: -217px;
    margin-top: 41px;
    padding: 9px 0;
}




<!-- End Slide Show Styles -->
```

Comment: Set up a fiddle for us at http://www.jsfiddle.net - Use placeholder images instead of your relative image links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see an unnecessary `a` tag here,

```
<div id="main_view">

    <img src="img/appimg_1.jpg" alt="" /></a><br />

</div>
```

What is this doing there. Maybe this is creating an issue and disturbing the whole script, please post a fiddle, if issue still persists.

Comment: Thanks so much for checking it out - it didn't fix the problem though. I'm not sure what a fiddle means - but I've posted a screenshot of the problem for a better visual, and that is all the code. Recheck above and check out the link to see what I mean.

Comment: Are you seeing this in Firefox, Can you change the name of class hover to something different, there is a known bug in firefox while using hover as a class name.

Comment: Just tested across Chrome & Safari and same issue - so can't be that. Thanks though

Comment: @LouieLouie77 Go to http://doc.jsfiddle.net/ to know more about Fiddle and http://jsfiddle.net/ to start using it. I would recommend to read the documentation first.

Comment: I will create a fiddle momentarily to continue this question - thanks for the response. Off-topic subquestion about Fiddle; Can I save my tests to my Desktop?

Comment: You Can't save the fiddle webpage as a page hoping that it next time when I launch the page, it will work properly, but u can have ur scripts on fiddle and they are portable provided you create an account on fiddle